# Ejecutar aplicaciones GUI de Java en Visual studio Code web

Tags: java, web, vscode, github

Estoy practicando Java y ya tengo subido parte del curso a GitHub y quería usar el `CodeSpace` de GitHub para continuar con el curso en el trabajo ya que estoy todo el día fuera de casa y no puedo practicar, no puedo instalar nada en la PC por eso hago esto.

Me tira el error:

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:166)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:553)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:428)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:393)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
        at marcoCuadroTexto.<init>(App.java:26)
        at App.main(App.java:17)
@k-kurt ➜ /workspaces/codespaces-blank/probando $  cd /workspaces/codespaces-blank/probando ; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.5-ms/bin/java @/tmp/cp_emvlzwt9pj5wk8isuclt7uif2.argfile App 
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:166)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:553)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:428)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:393)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
        at marcoCuadroTexto.<init>(App.java:22)
        at App.main(App.java:13)
```

Vi que se puede hacer con el SSH remoto pero no deja instalar eso en el visual studio code web
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas en un ambiente headless, es decir sin interfaz grafica. Tal como te lo sugiere el error una manera es instalar un emulador de pantalla como el servidor X11. Inténtalo,  actualiza tu pregunta y si aun no funciona te ayudamos. Yo lo he hecho pero en travisCI, así que hasta no ver que errores te da en codespaces no sabría como ayudarte.